# Better way to get value from a data snapshot?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, operator-overloading, inline

In Android Studio, using Firebase Realtime Database and Kotlin, to retrieve the value of a node, you would have the following code:

```
val parentNodePath: String = "nodeParentPath"
val nodePath: String = "nodePath"

val nodeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(parentNodePath)

var value: Int

nodeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
override fun onDataChange(dS: DataSnapshot) {
    value = dS.child(nodePath).getValue(Int::Class.java)!!
    //or also 
    //value = dS.child(nodePath).value as Int
}

override fun onCancelled(dE: DatabaseError) {}
})
```

Would it be ok to define an extension function which implements the `get` operator overload to retrieve the value in a path, and would it be better to use `inline` keyword too, so when it runs, it doesn't have to call the function and instead it gets inlined inside the code?

```
/*inline*/ operator fun DataSnapshot.get(path: String): Any? =
    this.child(path).value
```

It would be used as `value = dS[nodePath] as Int`

Comment: What do you mean by "is it OK"? Does this work the way you want? Are you anticipating an objection, and if so, what?

Comment: I mean, will there be any performance issues? I implemented it and it works just fine, I don't know if it will cause any problems at a larger scale

Comment: If you want to know if there are performance problems, you should benchmark it.  But honestly, I think this is too small to worry about at all until you actually observe a performance problem.